# Random rotation of a set of distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: random-matrices

Consider a set $\{\mathbf{X}_1,\cdots , \mathbf{X}_M\}$ of distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $M$ finite. The $M$ values of the $i$-th coordinate do not all have to be dinstinct. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the points could be placed on a regular grid so that several points have the same x or y coordinates.

Let's now consider a rotation, that maps the original set into a new set $\{\mathbf{X}_1', \cdots, \mathbf{X}_M'\}$.

I would like to show that if we select the rotation randomly, i.e. if we project on a random orthogonal basis, the $M$ values of the $i$-th coordinates of the new set will be distinct for all $i=1, \cdots, n$ with probability almost one.

Intuitively it sounds like that should be the case. But I have no experience with random matrices and I wonder where I could start from to prove it.

Comment: The set of rotations forms a compact group $SO(n)$. The result you are looking for comes from results in algebraic geometry applied to this group, with a little measure theory at the end.

Comment: You can also use a counting type argument based on a geometric interpretation. Draw hyper planes including the points, so that a rotation of the point set to one with agreement on some coordinates means "making one of the planes vertical". How often can you do this?  Gerhard "Not Very Often, I'd Say" Paseman, 2018.04.26.

Answer (score 1):

For any two distinct integers $l,m \in \{1,\ldots, M\}$, let us define $\mathbb{P}_{lm}$;   be the $(n-1)$-dimensional space consisting of vectors in $v \in \mathbb{R}_n$ satisfying $v^T(\mathbf{X}_l-\mathbf{X}_m) = 0$ Then as long as $\mathbf{X}_l-\mathbf{X}_m$ is nonzero the probability that a randomly chosen vector of norm 1 from ${\mathbb{R}}_n$ lands in $\mathbb{P}_{lm}$ is 0 (as it would be for any $(n-1)$-dimensional space).

So let $A$ be the randomly chosen matrix from $SO_3$. For any positive integers $l,m \le M$ and $p \le n$ only way $A\mathbf{X}_l$ and $A\mathbf{X}_m$ can agree on the $p$-th coordinate is if the $p$-th row $v_p$ of $A$ is in $\mathbb{P}_{lm}$. However, given $A$ randomly chosen from $SO_3$ according to the uniform distribution, then for **any** **one** such integer $p$, the $p$-th row $v_p$ of $A$ is also chosen according to the uniform distribution from the set of vectors of norm 1. The probability of $v_p$ so chosen being in $\mathbb{P}_{lm}$ is 0. Thus, for **any** **one** choice of $p,l,m$ the probability that the $p$-th coordinate of $A\mathbf{X}_l$ equals the $p$-th coordinate of $\mathbf{X}_m$ is 0. To conclude that the probability is 0 that there is **any** such $p,l,m$ where the $p$-th coordinate of $A\mathbf{X}_l$ equals the $p$-th coordinate of $\mathbf{X}_m$ use the Union Bound; only $nM^2$ such choices for $p,l,m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go through it in detail. It might take a bit cause I am not used to this sort of proofs.